# Unable to call function cloud_functions

Tags: flutter

I keep getting:

> flutter: caught generic exception
>
> flutter: Exception: Unable to call function helloWorld.

I've been using cloud_functions 0.4.1

```dart
CloudFunctions cf = CloudFunctions(region: 'us-central1');
  try {
    HttpsCallable callable = cf.getHttpsCallable(
      functionName: 'helloWorld',
    );

    dynamic resp = await callable.call();

    print(resp);
  } on CloudFunctionsException catch (e) {
    print('caught firebase functions exception');
    print(e.code);
    print(e.message);
    print(e.details);
  } catch (e) {
    print('caught generic exception');
    print(e);
  }
```

Comment: You are using HTTP Callable function. Why not make the standard REST call ?

Answer (score 0):

NVM! I figured out what when I deployed my cloud function on firebase, I was deploying one for https requests not for calls. For anyone else in the future, use functions.https.onCall when making your method to deploy.